# Oleh Al Shulchan Melachim: Taking food from one country to another

Tags: halacha, bishul-akum

The halacha is that Bishul Akum only applies to something which is Oleh Al Shulchan Melachim. The poskim (Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 113, Chochmas Adam Klal 66) say that this is defined according to the custom of each individual country. What would be the halacha if something was cooked in a country where the food is NOT Oleh Al Shulchan Melachim and is then taken to a country where it IS Oleh Al Shulchan Milachim? Does the food become forbidden?

Comment: "The poskim say that this is defined according to the custom of each individual country." Sourcing this claim would improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Would the person who eats the food in his home country retroactively become chayav if he travels (what if it is already in his mouth or stomach)?

Comment: I would think that to be too far of a stretch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ben Ish Chai [Chukas 2:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_2nd_Year%2C_Chukat.12.1?lang=bi) brings from R’ Chaim Vital and others that in this case it would be prohibited:

> אפונים שקורין בערבי "חומץ" (חומוס) שקלו אותם הגויים כתב רבנו הרב חיים ויטל ז"ל בשער טעמי המצוות, פרשת עקב, בשם רבנו האר"י ז"ל, דאסורים מדינא, לפי דאלו הקליות שלהם עולין על שולחן מלכים ושרים של אותם המקומות שעושין אותם הקליות, עיין שם. ומדבריו משמע דאוסר אותם גם במקום שאין עולין על שולחן מלכים או שרים, מפני שבמקום שעושין אותם עולין

> ועיין "חיים שאל", חלק א, סימן עד, אות ו, שחקר בזה, וסוף דבר דעתו נטה לאסור גם במקום שאין עולין

In the reverse case, Rav Belsky and Rav Falk (Teshovus, Bishul Yisroel) are quoted as saying that it would also be prohibited. See [Halachapedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bishul_Akum#cite_ref-66) and [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/220229/halachically-speaking-bishul-akum-the-basics.html)

Comment: Translational question -- is that talking about what we think of as chumus?

Comment: Is he saying they brought the cooked chummus to a new place, or that chummus is prohibited everywhere because in that place where its commonly cooked, it's fancy?

Comment: @double AA kaf hachaim 113:20 is more explicit that it refers to product that travelled. https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.113.20.1?lang=bi

Comment: @rosends צ in sefardi pronunciation is not an affricate. Modern Israeli צ is ashkenazi.

Comment: I'm just wondering because chumus, itself, isn't cooked. The chickpeas might be boiled but would the question then be about chickpeas and not the subsequent chumus?

Comment: Where can I find Rav Falks sefer?

Comment: I think it’s in Machzeh Eliyohu chelek Beis. I can’t find it online, they only have chelek alef

Comment: @rosends "חומוס" just means "chickpeas", the dish we know as hummus in English is technically referred to as hummus b'tahina in Hebrew